# Show that $H$ is isomorphic to $xHx^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, let $H ≤ G$, and let $x \in G$.  $xHx^{-1}$ is the set of elements $\{xhx^{-1}|h∈H\}$.  I have already proven that $xHx^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$ by showing $*$ is closed and finding an inverse is closed, but now I need to show $xHx^{-1}$ and $H$ are isomorphic.  I want to show this because once we know this then we know $|H|=|xHx^{-1}|$.  In order to show this we must show a bijection exists between these two and a homomorphism exists between the two.  How would you go about to show this?  A few questions on here have talked about $H=xHx^{-1}$ but not if they are isomorphic.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The isomorphism is $\phi(g) = xgx^{-1}$. Try to verify that this map is a homomorphism.

Comment: Okay so I think I got it!  To show this is a homomorphism let x,y ∈ $Z$.  (xy)=($xHx^{-1}$)($yHy^{-1}$)=(x)(y). So this is a homomorphism.

Comment: Once you've verified that the map is a homomorphism, you also need to confirm that its kernel is trivial to show that it's an isomorphism.

Comment: @user710744 that's not correct, the homomorphism isn't $\phi(x)=xHx^{-1}$, notice that the RHS is actually a subgroup, not a member, of $G$. What even is $Z$ and how is that relevant to our discussion here?

Comment: @YiFan I'm using x and y as elements in the integers that exist in H.  I'm using the map that was provided above what is your idea then?

Comment: @user710744 $H$ is a general group, $\mathbb Z$ is not even related to the discussion here. And no, the given map by Dane, which is correct, takes some $g\in H$ to $xgx^{-1}$ in $xHx^{-1}$, which is completely different from taking $x\in H$ to $xHx^{-1}$. It looks like you have a very deep misconception regarding what groups are.